# Keep relationships between many-to-many fields django-tables2

Tags: django, database, postgresql, many-to-many, django-tables2

I'm working on the development of a web with Django and PostgreSQL and I'm using the app [django-tables2](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2) to create HTML tables.

```
class SampleTable(ColumnShiftTableBootstrap4):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ("name", "sample_id_sex", "pools", "indexes", "gene_cand_lists",)
```

My database collects Next Generation Sequencing (NGS) data. `sample_id_sex` is a foreign key (1:N relationship) while `pools`, `indexes` and `gene_cand_lists` are many-to-many fields, the combination of these three rows are unique: in other words, they are related.

My problem is that in each row the values are ordered by default. For example, the sample X belongs to the pool CES001 and has the index B2 and the gene list list3 but it also belongs to the pool CES002 with the index A1 and list1. In the table, they should appear like this (`,` as the separator in the many-to-many columns):

| sample | sex | pools | indexes | gene_lists |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-009 | male | CES001, CES002 | B2, A1 | list3, list1 |

But they appear like this:

| sample | sex | pools | indexes | gene_lists |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-009 | male | CES001, CES002 | A1, B2 | list1, list3 |

The relationships between the three fields are broken. Is there a way to correct this? And the separator could be a newline and not a comma?

Edit: I think the question is not clear enough. The model of the sample table is:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
   id_sample = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
   indexes = models.ManyToManyField(Index, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', blank=True)
   pools = models.ManyToManyField(Index, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', blank=True)
   gene_lists = models.ManyToManyField(Index, through='SamplePoolIndexCand', blank=True)
```

And the intermediate table:

```
class SamplePoolIndexCand(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.ForeignKey(Sample, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_sample', 
    verbose_name='Mostra')
    pool_id = models.ForeignKey(Pool, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='id_pool', 
    verbose_name='Pool')    
    index_id = models.ForeignKey(Index, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    db_column='id_index', verbose_name='Índex')
    gene_cand_list_id = models.ForeignKey(GeneCandList, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    db_column='id_gene_cand_list', verbose_name='Llista de gens candidats')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ordering tag in your models particular class of many to many fields

```
class gene_lists(models.Model):    
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=16383)

class indexes(models.Model):
   contents = models.ManyToManyField(gene_lists, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['priority', 'contents']
```

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was incomplete... I'll add the sample and intermediate tables models to make it clearer. What I want is to keep the relationships of the many to many fields, each entry has a unique combination.